# WordPress custom pagination not showing on custom post type

Tags: wordpress, post, types, pagination

My custom pagination function is not returning any value when I call the function in my custom post type loop, I can't figure out why.

My pagination function works for the homepage but just not for custom post types, I'm also using it for my WooCommerce pagination and it's working fine there.

This is my loop:

```
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type'=>'winners',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
  <?php
    endwhile;
    topdraw_pagination();
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

This is my pagination function:

```
<?php
function topdraw_pagination() {
    if( is_singular() ) {
        return;
    }
    global $wp_query;
    if( $wp_query->max_num_pages <= 1 ) {
        return;
    }
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
    $max = intval( $wp_query->max_num_pages );
    if( $paged >= 1 ) {
        $links[] = $paged;
    }
    if( $paged >= 3 ) {
        $links[] = $paged - 1;
    }
    if( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
        $links[] = $paged + 1;
    }
    echo '<nav class="pagination">' . "\n";
    if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) {
        printf( '%s' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('<span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i></span>') );
    }
    if ( get_next_posts_link() ) {
        printf( '%s' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('<span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>') );
    }
    echo '<ul class="pagination-list">' . "\n";
    if( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
        $class = 1 == $paged ? ' is-current' : '';
        $aria_current = 1 == $paged ? ' aria-current="page"' : '';
        printf( '<li><a href="%s" class="pagination-link%s" aria-label="Goto page 1"%s>%s</a></li>' . "\n", esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), $class, $aria_current, '1' );
        if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) ) {
            echo '<li><span class="pagination-ellipsis">&hellip;</span></li>' . "\n";
        }
    }
    sort( $links );
    foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
        $class = $paged == $link ? ' is-current' : '';
        $aria_current = $paged == $link ? ' aria-current="page"' : '';
        printf( '<li><a href="%s" class="pagination-link%s" aria-label="Goto page %s"%s>%s</a></li>' . "\n", esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $class, $link, $aria_current, $link );
    }
    if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
        if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) ) {
            echo '<li><span class="pagination-ellipsis">&hellip;</span></li>' . "\n";
        }
        $class = $paged == $max ? ' is-current' : '';
        $aria_current = $paged == $max ? ' aria-current="page"' : '';
        printf( '<li><a href="%s" class="pagination-link%s" aria-label="Goto page %s"%s>%s</a></li>' . "\n", esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $class, $max, $aria_current, $max );
    }
    echo '</ul></nav>' . "\n";
}

add_filter( 'next_posts_link_attributes', 'topdraw_next_posts_link_class' );
add_filter( 'previous_posts_link_attributes', 'topdraw_previous_posts_link_class' );

function topdraw_next_posts_link_class() {
    return 'class="pagination-next"';
}

function topdraw_previous_posts_link_class() {
    return 'class="pagination-previous"';
}
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Your CPT loop is displayed on a page? Where does the execution end?

Comment: @Michael Not too sure what you mean? The loop is on a page yes

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your custom WP_Query instance to your pagination function, instead of using the global `$wp_query`

```
  $args = array(
   'post_type'=>'winners',
   'posts_per_page' => 6,
   'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1,
  );
  $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
  if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
     the_title(); ?>
   endwhile;

   topdraw_pagination( $loop );
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
```

And your function:

```
function topdraw_pagination( $loop ) {

 if( is_singular() ) {
    return;
 }

 if( $loop->max_num_pages <= 1 ) {
    return;
 }

 $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
 $max = intval( $loop->max_num_pages );
 if( $paged >= 1 ) {
    $links[] = $paged;
 }
 if( $paged >= 3 ) {
    $links[] = $paged - 1;
 }
 if( ( $paged + 2 ) <= $max ) {
    $links[] = $paged + 1;
 }
 echo '<nav class="pagination">' . "\n";
 if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) {
    printf( '%s' . "\n", get_previous_posts_link('<span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i></span>') );
 }
 if ( get_next_posts_link() ) {
    printf( '%s' . "\n", get_next_posts_link('<span class="icon is-small"><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></span>') );
 }
 echo '<ul class="pagination-list">' . "\n";
 if( ! in_array( 1, $links ) ) {
    $class = 1 == $paged ? ' is-current' : '';
    $aria_current = 1 == $paged ? ' aria-current="page"' : '';
    printf( '<li><a href="%s" class="pagination-link%s" aria-label="Goto page 1"%s>%s</a></li>' . "\n", esc_url( get_pagenum_link( 1 ) ), $class, $aria_current, '1' );
    if ( ! in_array( 2, $links ) ) {
        echo '<li><span class="pagination-ellipsis">&hellip;</span></li>' . "\n";
    }
 }
 sort( $links );
 foreach ( (array) $links as $link ) {
    $class = $paged == $link ? ' is-current' : '';
    $aria_current = $paged == $link ? ' aria-current="page"' : '';
    printf( '<li><a href="%s" class="pagination-link%s" aria-label="Goto page %s"%s>%s</a></li>' . "\n", esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $link ) ), $class, $link, $aria_current, $link );
 }
 if ( ! in_array( $max, $links ) ) {
    if ( ! in_array( $max - 1, $links ) ) {
        echo '<li><span class="pagination-ellipsis">&hellip;</span></li>' . "\n";
    }
    $class = $paged == $max ? ' is-current' : '';
    $aria_current = $paged == $max ? ' aria-current="page"' : '';
    printf( '<li><a href="%s" class="pagination-link%s" aria-label="Goto page %s"%s>%s</a></li>' . "\n", esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $max ) ), $class, $max, $aria_current, $max );
 }
 echo '</ul></nav>' . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't fix it, the pagination still doesn't display

Comment: I tested this code on my local machine and it worked. Well, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by renaming $loop to $wp_query in my custom post type loop. If someone could explain why this fixed the problem I would appreciate it.